# Moduli space of complex Tori

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, moduli-spaces, kahler-manifolds

Is there any explicit computation for the Weil-Petersson metric on moduli space of Tori of complex dimension n?

Comment: There is no reasonable moduli space for complex tori, see [this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/126328/moduli-spaces-of-higher-dimensional-complex-tori).

Comment: I couldn't find anything in your link that such moduli space may not exists, can you explain for me?

Comment: As explained in the link, the set of isomorphism classes of complex tori of dimension $d$ is the quotient of $GL(2d,\mathbb{R})/GL(d,\mathbb{C})$ by the discrete group $GL(2d,\mathbb{Z})$. However the action of $GL(2d,\mathbb{Z})$ is not properly discontinuous, so the resulting quotient space is not Hausdorff (and in particular not metrizable).