Moduli space of complex and anti-complex tori?
$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$By Will Sawin's answer to Moduli Spaces of Higher Dimensional Complex Tori the moduli space of complex $d$-tori is $X = \GL_{d}(\mathbb{C})\backslash{\GL_{2d}(\mathbb{R})}/{\GL_{2d}(\mathbb{Z})}$.
What would happen if complex structures which are anti-biholomorphic equivalent were also identified? If the resulting space is $Y$ would the canonical map $Y \to X$ be a $2$-sheeted covering? Is there a reference for such moduli spaces?
I don't think so because if $d = 1$ it would be
$$X \cong \mathbb{R}^*{\SO(2)}\backslash{\GL_2(\mathbb{R})}/{\GL_2(\mathbb{Z})} \cong \SO(2)\backslash{\SL_2(\mathbb{R})}/{\SL_2(\mathbb{Z})} \cong \mathbb{H}/{\SL_2(\mathbb{Z})}\cong \mathbb{R^2}$$
and
$$Y \cong \mathbb{R}^*O(2)\backslash{\GL_2(\mathbb{R})}/{\GL_2(\mathbb{Z})} \cong (\SO(2)\backslash{\SL_2(\mathbb{R})})/{\GL_2(\mathbb{Z})}\cong \mathbb{H}/{\GL_2(\mathbb{Z})} \cong \mathbb{R}^2_+ = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ y \geq 0\}$$
so $X \to Y$ cannot be a $2$-sheeted covering?

You can probably realize $Y$ as an orbifold with $X$ its 2-sheeted covering in orbifold sense. But as you note, it will not be so as topological spaces. $Y$ will not be a manifold, it will have a "boundary" corresponding to tori isomorphic to their conjugates.

@Wojowu So, are the above homeomorphisms in the case $d=1$ for $X$ and $Y$ correct? It would then imply that the only complex tori which are isomorphic to the anti-complex structure would be the rectangular tori? Is there a reference for this moduli space or has it no significance?

It should be the rectangular and the "isosceles tori", the latter being ones with a lattice basis of the form ${1,\frac{1}{2}+ib}$ for some $b\in\mathbb R$. However your homeomorphism should be correct, since the isomorphism with $\mathbb R^2\cong\mathbb C$ corresponds to taking $j$-invariant, and the invariant tori are the ones with real $j$-invariant.

@Wojowu First I thought the homeomorphisms are correct. But right now I am a bit confused: wouldn't  also $$Y \cong \mathbb{R}^*O(2)\backslash GL_2(\mathbb{R})/GL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \cong SO(2)\backslash SL_2(\mathbb{R})/SL_2(\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{H}/SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{R}^2$$ because by $O(2)$ on the left matrices with negative determinant don't matter? But this cannot be true on the other hand since $\mathbb{R}^2_+ \ncong \mathbb{R}^2$ and then we would have $X \cong Y$?

The left and right actions of negative matrices don't coincide, so you cannot just arbitrarily forget them on the right just because they act on the left too.

@Wojowu Ok, then my first thought was correct, so the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ acts non trivially on $\mathbb{R}^*O(2)\backslash GL_2(\mathbb{R}) \cong SO(2)\backslash SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and translates into $z \mapsto -\bar z$ on $\mathbb{H}$ which folds the upper half plane at the imaginary axis, which gives $\mathbb{R}^*O(2)\backslash GL_2(\mathbb{R})/GL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{C}/\sim (z \mapsto \bar z) \cong \mathbb{R}^2_+$?

I would strongly encourage you to think about what happens when $d=2$. In this case, the moduli space is the 2-dimensional hyperbolic orbifold with one cusp, one cone point of order 2 and one cone point of order 3. You can also visualise it as the fundamental domain for the action of $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ on the upper half-plane, pictured here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ModularGroup-FundamentalDomain.svg .  The antiholomophic involution is reflection in the imaginary axis, so the fundamental domain is divided into a single triangle, and the quotient moduli space is a triangle orbifold.

(My comment crossed with yours. It looks like you're figuring it out!) The "covering" map is the quotient map from the cusped orbifold to the triangle. This is a covering of orbifolds, but not of topological spaces.

@HJRW I think this is still $d=1$? In the case $d \geq 2$ I don't have a good visualization of what is going on. But maybe it is analogous to the $1$-dimensional case. But the $d=1$ case is now relatively clear to me.

@psl2Z: Yes, sorry, I am thinking of the real dimension.

In your displayed formula for $Y$, should the third term be $\operatorname{SO}(2)\backslash{\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R)}/{\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z)}$ instead of $(\operatorname{SO}(2)\backslash{\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R)}){\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z)}$? If not, then what does the latter mean? If so, then how does $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ act on $\operatorname{SO}(2)\backslash{\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R)}$?

@LSpice It should read $(SO(2)\backslash SL_2(\mathbb{R}))/GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, because one can identify the spaces $\mathbb{R}^* O(2)\backslash GL_2(\mathbb{R}) \cong SO(2)\backslash SL_2(\mathbb{R})$. Then one takes the "old" action of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ on $\mathbb{R}^* O(2)\backslash GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and transports it onto $SO(2)\backslash SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ via the homeomorphism.

@LSpice But as mentioned in the comments above one cannot eliminate the negative determinant matrices on the right, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^*O(2)\backslash GL_2(\mathbb{R})/GL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \ncong SO(2)\backslash SL_2(\mathbb{R})/SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

For $d$ odd these two components are disconnected, because $I$ and $-I$ induce opposite orientation. For $d$ even, you have an involution, which takes a lattice to a complex conjugate lattice. This involution takes a lattice
$\tau_1, \dotsc, \tau_{2d}$ to a complex conjugate lattice
$\bar\tau_1, \dotsc, \bar\tau_{2d}$, and has many fixed points.
$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$However, be very careful about this:
"By this https://mathoverflow.net/q/126329 the moduli space of complex $d$-tori is $X = \GL_{d}(\mathbb{C})\backslash{\GL_{2d}(\mathbb{R})}/{\GL_{2d}(\mathbb{Z})}$": for $d\geq 2$, this double quotient is very non-Hausdorff,
because $\GL_{2d}(\mathbb{Z})$ acts on $\GL_{d}(\mathbb{C})\backslash{\GL_{2d}(\mathbb{R})}$ with dense orbits, as follows from Ratner theory.
It's not very good idea to consider this quotient as an orbifold, because it has codiscrete topology: all open sets are either empty or everything.
Detailed explanation is found in Ergodic complex structures on hyperkahler manifolds.

Thank you for the reference. It looks interesting. What do you mean by "these two components"? The two sheets of the "covering"? And what do you mean by "orientation"? I think if we had real dimensions then $-I$ would induce the opposite orientation if and only if $d$ was odd? Further, then it is not interesting/ useless to study the moduli space for $d \geq 2$ topologically, i.e. only the $1$-dimensional case gives an interesting moduli space?

In particular all moduli spaces for $d \geq 2$ would simply be homeomorphic to $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ with the trivial topology $\tau$?

Complex structure on a vector space defines the orientation. Two components are complex structures with the opposite orientation. The correspondence $I \mapsto -I$ identifies these two components when dimension is odd, and produces an involution on the Teichmuller space of complex structures when it is even.

Ok. I was first confused and thought that $I$ was the indentity. But $I$ is the complex structure. In the case that $d$ is even, doesn't $I \mapsto -I$ produce the identity on the Teichmüller space and the moduli spaces of complex and of complex/anticomplex structures are thus equal in the case $d$ even? In the case $d$ odd $I \mapsto -I$ produces an involution on the Teichmüller space? For example in case $d = 1$ it gives $\cong \mathbb{C}$ for the moduli space complex structures and $\cong {\text{Im}(z) \geq 0}$ for the moduli space of complex/anticomplex structures?

Since for $d=1$ it is $\mathbb{R}^*SO(2)\backslash GL_2(\mathbb{R})/GL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^*O(2)\backslash GL_2(\mathbb{R})/GL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \cong {\text{Im}(z) \geq 0}$.
